# "w" command doesn't show different terminal sessions Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: shell, ubuntu-16.04

When I try running the `w` command. It only shows the user logged in, not each terminal session separately. Is there any way to fix this or is this part of the version itself?

Comment: What happens if you run `who`?

Comment: @jeremysprofile it shows even less info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different terminal than GNOME Terminal.  Most terminal emulators update *utmp* for each terminal window (which is why you do not see the expected information); the GNOME Terminal developers chose to not do that.  Ubuntu 16.04 has several choices including xterm, rxvt-unicode, XFCE Terminal, Terminology, Konsole, mlterm, PuTTY.